# JMETER - Try to test UCP messages

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to search a way to test an IP an a specific port which is made to receive UCP messages (SMS).
I would like to do the test with Jmeter but I don't find anything on the web that helps me on this way.
The goal of the test is to manage differents users. Each user simulates a mobile phone. Each user have to send an amount of SMS (UCP protocol) per seconde to the server.
For each message sent I have also to check if the response is correct (find ACK in the UCP response) and then send an other specific message.

If you have a solution for this thank you a lot I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box JMeter doesn't support UCP protocol, however you can consider using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) in order to create UCP messages programmatically.

1. Obtain a Java Library which implements UCP protocol, for example [RSMS Ucp](http://www.java4less.com/RSmsUcp_help.html) and drop it into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the library up
3. Add JSR223 Sampler to your Test Plan
4. Write the relevant code using Java or Groovy syntax, the minimum would be something like:

   ```
   import com.java4less.comm.ModemConnector
   import com.java4less.sms.SmsMessage
   import com.java4less.sms.tap.TapSender

   def connector = new ModemConnector("number to dial", "AT init command", "port", 9600, 8, 1, 'N')
   def message = new SmsMessage("recipient number", "message text");
   def sender = new TapSender(connector, "TAP password");
   def success = sender.sendMessage(message)
   ```